# error: intento de leer o escribir fuera del disco hd0 debe cargar el nucleo primero

Tags: linux

recien instalé win 10 en un equipo viejo. La board es asrock g41m-v3. aumenté la ram y tambien instalé el sistema operativo en un ssd. Junto con windows 10, instalé ububtu 22.04 pero al intentar ingresar a ubuntu me aparece el error que mencioné anteriormente. Lo que he encontrado es que se debe a una configuración (la cual no se como modificar) en la bios para deshabilitar el arranque seguro. Dicha opción no está en la bios de mi equipo. Intenté restablecer el grub, reinstalé ubunto varias veces, deshabilité el arranque rapido de windows 10, probé configuraciones con iso de linux live en una usb, pero me sigue apareciendo el error. Al parecer hay algun conflicto con los sistemas operativos y el grub en el MBR... NECESITO AYUDA!!!

Comment: cual es el error que aparece, pero en ingles? tienes instalado el arranque de grub en el disco ?

Comment: Parece un error de grub, podrías intentar lo mencionado en [este artículo](https://usuariodebian.blogspot.com/2021/10/error-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside.html). Por otra parte, según los [sistemas operativos soportados](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/348005/Asrock-G41m-Vgs3.html?page=51#manual), la motherboard es muy antigua y no tiene opción de arranque seguro, por lo que eso no debe ser parte del problema.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, al parecer solo debía desmontar la participación del arranque de Windows y después reinstalar Linux y después del primer inicio de Linux, reiniciar e ingresar a Windows (la partición se montará sola ) cabe aclarar que lo intenté con fedora y pues me quedaré ahí mientras puedo comprar una PC nueva.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucioné, al parecer solo debía desmontar la participación del arranque de Windows (la de 50mb reservada para el sistema), después reinstalar Linux y después del primer inicio de Linux, reiniciar e ingresar a Windows (la partición se montará sola ) cabe aclarar que lo intenté con fedora y pues me quedaré ahí mientras puedo comprar una PC nueva.